# Sysctl permission denied

Tags: networking, permissions

Today I tried to download Hamachi/Haguichi with the setup they have. It seemed to work but I couldn't connect. The power button wouldn't do anything but say it's connecting then say it's disconnected. I looked it up, and the some other people had the problem as well. They said to just enable Ipv6 with a command:

```
sysctl net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=0
```

It said:

```
sysctl: permission denied on key 'net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6'
```

I do not know much about Linux/Ubuntu, but I've tried:

```
su
```

and it asked for my password, then when I typed it, it said

```
su: Authentication failure
```

Any help would be useful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Do enable IPv6 on your machine, edit the `99-sysctl.conf` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/sysctl.d/99-sysctl.conf
```

Look for those three lines in that file:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 0
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 0
```

If they are there already, they might have a '1' at the end. Change the '1' to '0' on each of these three lines.
Else add those three lines at the bottom of that file, then save changes and quit the editor.

Now execute this command to load the above changes:

```
sudo sysctl -p
```

At this point IPv6 is permanently enabled on your system.

To disable IPv6 again, edit the file, change the three values from '0' to '1', save, and run `sudo sysctl -p` again.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this hasn't worked. I'm not sure what is actually making Haguichi not work, but apparently it isn't Ipv6. If it helps I run an old windows but needed more ram, so I switched it to Lubuntu.